# TextDelegate not recognizing a textfield after hidden = NO

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2

I have a textfield that is hidden to start with and when the user touches a UISwitch the `textfield.hidden= NO`, however, the `-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` doesn't kick in?  any ideas

thanks

Comment: don't forget to link the delegate (UITextField).

Comment: just another note - the delegate is UITextFieldDelegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

textFieldDidBeginEditing will get called when the textField becomes the first responder.  If the user sets focus in the field to start changing it's content, it becomes the first responder.  It will not get called when the enabled state gets toggled.  If it's hidden, the user will not be able to edit it's content.

See:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html

> This method notifies the delegate that the specified text field just
>   became the first responder. You can use this method to update your
>   delegate’s state information. For example, you might use this method
>   to show overlay views that should be visible while editing.
>
> Implementation of this method by the delegate is optional.

Comment: I should have been clearer.  When the user starts to edit in the textfield that is no longer hidden, I expected the methods to kick in but it doesn't

Comment: Actually I solved my problem by is isFirstResponder because I had a NSNotification method which was being called before any of the text delegate methods.  Thanks for the help